# Is there any specific reason to choose ORC file format for transaction tables in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro, orc

Is there any specific reason to choose ORC file format for transaction tables in hive? Why cannot we use AVRO instead?At least from the structural perspective AVRO is row oriented and closer to RDBMS structure.

Comment: what do you stop to use Avro or even RC file format to store data? define a file format is just necessary for the stored and recovery of data by HDFS. In my experience, for Hive is better to use Avro or SequenceFile format than ORC.

Comment: Please read the limitation section in hive transactions at cwiki.apache.org, where orc file is mentioned as a limitation.

Comment: ok, let me see it and then i could give you an advice

Comment: Well, it seems like an optimized of RCFile format, pretty similar to Parquet. But it doesn't say something that is recommended to use for transactional data. In my opinion, it seems like is better to use due to its compression and reduce of job in MR Tasks, Furthermore, remember hive is a dw so you suppose to use it for query data and not like an OLTP database. it loss sense in this context.

Comment: I dont think we can use any file format for a full transactional table. Please read the below..There are two types of ACID tables:

Insert-only (“micromanaged”) tables that provide ACID semantics but only allow insert operations. They can store data in any format. Create one like:


Insert, update, delete (“full transactional”) tables that provide ACID semantics for all insert, update and delete operations. They must use the ORC file format.

Comment: And I know have is for OLAP. But want to know how ORC is helping hive to get acid transactional tables.

Comment: Or, you can use Kudu https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Kudu+Integration and forget about ACID.

Comment: @RajeshSarkar ok   I'd research a little bit more. please if you find the answer, post it!! it'd be nice for the community